# Skrollr Issues On iOS

Tags: javascript

I have no trouble whatsoever getting the effects to work on the desktop although the page length becomes slightly longer than it should be. However, when I switch to viewing the page on my iPhone 5, the bottom part of the page gets cut off.

I am using relative mode for all my animations as absolute mode completely screws up the animations on the iPhone (all the content becomes invisible).

What can I do to ensure that the experience is consistent across all devices? I am still testing out the site and am hoping to launch it end of the month (so can't share the link where I'm testing it).

Comment: Are you using simple html,css and jquery or are you using any libraries like jquerymobile, sencha for the purpose. Also For animations, are you using any external plugin or just jquery. If you are doing cross platform websites, you generally dont use "px" and also you dont give height="--px". You might be restricting the size somewhere and thats why its getting cut off in iphone view. Sharing the code here will do good for you.

Comment: I am not using any other files besides jquery and a small script to build a select box menu for mobile. I only have height in px for the top navigation area which is fixed to the top of the screen. I have not used px anywhere else to define the heights.

Comment: I am also using skrollr-menu and using the following: data-menu-offset="-140" so that all the anchors on the site align nicely when anyone clicks on the anchor link in the navigation.

Comment: I answered a similar question over here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27844199/1935646