# Skrollr cutoff on iPad

Tags: javascript, skrollr

I am using Skrollr plugin and it's working fine on desktop.
On iPad though, the height of my document is cutoff. I have tried to remove all skrollr data attributes, but the issue persists, I noticed that just by activating the plugin I get this issue.

I tried to enable/disable the forceHeight option but the issue persists. Any idea?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue, too, but I fixed it by adding an empty **data-top** and **data-bottom** to the **#skrollr-body** div. (Though depending on how strict your HTML cleaners are, you may need to add **data-top=""** or **data-bottom=""**)

```
<body>
   <div id="skrollr-body" data-top data-bottom>
       Your content here.
   </div>
</body>
```

I'm still looking into the explanation of why this fix works, but I believe it has something to do with setting keyframes. By making sure your #skrollr-body has keyframes for top and bottom, it ensures both are seen in the viewport.

More details here: https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr/issues/576