# Skrollr height issue / content getting cutt off on iPad and touch devices

Tags: ios, ipad, touch, parallax, skrollr

I've been struggling with this one for a while.  I'm using skrollr on a new site, and it is working great on the desktop.  However, the content is getting cut off on ipad and android touch devices after turning the device from either landscape to portrait or vice versa.  It is very similar to the problem described here : [Skrollr cutoff on iPad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25608911/skrollr-cutoff-on-ipad), but the solution they recommended there is not fixing the problem for me.

This can sort of be fixed by adding padding to the bottom of the skrollr-body div, but the amount needed changes between portrait and landscape.  The page seems to need a refresh when that is changed, so CSS and media queries aren't cutting it for me at the time.

Any ideas?  Really digging Skrollr otherwise, but this is driving me crazy.

Here is the link for viewing : 
http://rweststaging.com/stackoverflow/test.php

Here is the basic code :

```
// Top fixed section
<div id="animation"
data-0p="position:fixed; top:0%;"
data-100p="position:fixed; top:0%;"
data-120p="position:fixed; top:0%;"
data-210p="position:fixed;  top:-130%; opacity:1; display:block;"
data-220p="opacity:0; display:none;"
>
</div>

//lower content section
<div id="skrollr-body" 
style="position: absolute; top: 220%; width: 100%;" 
data-top="" data-bottom=""
>
    //content sections go here
</div> // end skrollr body

//skroller init 
skroll = skrollr.init({
     // mobileCheck:function(){return false;},
     forceHeight:false,
     smoothScrolling: true,
     smoothScrollingDuration: 600
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I've experienced issues putting by not having the #skrollr-body div independent (as this inherits a new function when detecting mobile).

So try wrapping your #skrollr-body div around your div with sections -

```
// Top fixed section ...

<div id="skrollr-body" style=""> // no styles
    <div class="nonfixed" style="position:absolute; top:220%; width:100%;">
    // all non-fixed elements
    </div>
</div>
```